# Marketing Cloud SDK crash 8.0.11 Crash with error: Please add correct version of MarketingCloudSDK.bundle

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

I was previously using Marketing Cloud sdk 8.0.9 with MarketingCloud.bundle 8.0.8 which worked fine but my testflight build started crashing with error:

**Please add correct version of MarketingCloudSDK.bundle. Added version: 8.0.8, Correct version to be added : 8.0.11.**

I updated the bundle to version 8.0.11 and sfmc sdk to 1.0.7 which fixed the issue for fresh install. But the app is still crashing when app is upgraded from a previous version to the latest one with below error:

**Please add correct version of MarketingCloudSDK.bundle. Added version: 8.0.11, Correct version to be added : 5.31.0.**
(5.31.0) is my app version number. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Question: Why would you update the SDK and not copy in the corresponding bundle?

Comment: Now SDK version and bundle version are the same:
MarketingCloudSDK version: 8.0.11
MarketingCloudSDK.bundle: 8.0.11
SFMSDK: 1.0.7

Comment: Hi, while uploading the .ipa file to testflight, by any chance is "Manage Version and Build Number" option is  selected? This will change the versions of all the contents within the .ipa.

Comment: We use CI/CD so don't upload builds manually to testflight. But i checked the sdk state log. I can see it is 8.0.11.

Comment: The bundle check looks for CFBundleShortVersionString in the MarketingCloudSDK.bundle. It's not obvious to us why that would have your application's version there unless some process edited it. If this doesn't happen locally, my only suggestion would be to audit your CI/CD pipeline to see if there's even a small chance that it could be mutating the bundle in any way.

Comment: I have tried not using the CI/CD to upload build instead doing it manually via Project>Archive. When I uncheck "Manage version and Build number" , and proceed to upload the build the validation fails with error "The value for bundle_version in the metadata.xml file does not match the value for CFBundleVersion in 'App Name Here' [Payload/App Name.app].""

Note: In target , App target version and Notification extension target version are the same. Still the validation fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to verify that a relatively new Xcode setting (manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber) will alter our SDK’s ability to verify the versions of its components. The issue only surfaces when the application is published to the App Store or Testflight, and is not detectable during the build. The team felt that they needed to rollback the version and fix the issue in the next release.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, Please let us know when the fix is available. we have currently uploaded the build by manually creating the ipa.

Comment: Please update to the latest release (MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.12 & SFMCSDK 1.0.8)