# Marketing Cloud SDK crash 8.0.8 and then On upgrade to 8.0.11 - Please add correct version of MarketingCloudSDK.bundle, Added version: 8.0.8/8.0.11

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, ios, github-actions

We have been using 8.0.8 build and it was working fine till yesterday but all of the sudden, our Nightly builds releasing to TestFlight start crashing. So we have tried to update our SDK to 8.0.11 along with bundle version. **But the crash still persist.**

We have also seen [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/396027/128150), but no solution here too.

```
Fatal Exception: Invalid MarketingCloudSDK.bundle Added!
0  CoreFoundation                 0x99d78 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x16734 objc_exception_throw
2  MarketingCloudSDK              0xefd4 (Missing UUID 8d6eb5c2a1a63fac86018c1e6b7327e5)
3  MarketingCloudSDK              0xd444 (Missing UUID 8d6eb5c2a1a63fac86018c1e6b7327e5)
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x19060 (Missing UUID 8d6eb5c2a1a63fac86018c1e6b7327e5)
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x19424 (Missing UUID 8d6eb5c2a1a63fac86018c1e6b7327e5)
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x18300 (Missing UUID 8d6eb5c2a1a63fac86018c1e6b7327e5)
7  SFMCSDK                        0x4276c (Missing UUID 8537628da0e338e593aa70fac6f20c68)
8  SFMCSDK                        0x42830 (Missing UUID 8537628da0e338e593aa70fac6f20c68)
9  SFMCSDK                        0x1ed60 (Missing UUID 8537628da0e338e593aa70fac6f20c68)
10 Foundation                     0x4fae8 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__
11 Foundation                     0x5dc90 __NSOQSchedule_f
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x12830 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a2c _dispatch_client_callout
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x6eec _dispatch_continuation_pop
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x6558 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x15164 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1596c _dispatch_worker_thread2
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1080 _pthread_wqthread
```

Also here I am adding the configurations of my CI Job, which ensures the CI job is not modifying the bundle.

```
INFO [2023-02-14 18:25:38.33]: ▸ Cloning local copy of package ‘MarketingCloudSDK-iOS’
INFO [2023-02-14 18:25:38.40]: ▸ Checking out 8.0.11 of package ‘MarketingCloudSDK-iOS’
INFO [2023-02-14 18:25:42.39]: ▸ Cloning local copy of package ‘sfmc-sdk-ios’
INFO [2023-02-14 18:25:42.43]: ▸ Checking out 1.0.7 of package ‘sfmc-sdk-ios’


INFO [2023-02-14 18:27:07.75]: ▸   MarketingCloudSDK: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS @ 8.0.11
INFO [2023-02-14 18:27:07.75]: ▸   SFMCSDK: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios @ 1.0.7

INFO [2023-02-14 18:27:07.86]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./iOS-App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release


+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                         Summary for gym 2.211.0                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                                                            | XXXXXXXX                                                                                                                             |
| configuration                                                     | Release                                                                                                                              |
| clean                                                             | true                                                                                                                                 |
| skip_profile_detection                                            | true                                                                                                                                 |
| export_method                                                     | app-store                                                                                                                            |
| export_team_id                                                    | XUXXXXXXXX                                                                                                                           |
| output_name                                                       | iOS-Nightly                                                                                                                 |
| xcargs                                                            | build_type='DEBUG' branch_key='key_test_bfXuy2uobV1CiIwXKPjvJkboDCji7F9C' application_environment='DEV' -skipPackagePluginValidation |
| export_options.compileBitcode                                     | false                                                                                                                                |
| export_options.uploadBitcode                                      | false                                                                                                                                |
| export_options.method                                             | app-store                                                                                                                            |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.discovery.mobile| iOS Distribution                                                                                                            |
| workspace                                                         | ./iOS-App.xcworkspace                                                                                                       |
| output_directory                                                  | .                                                                                                                                    |
| silent                                                            | false                                                                                                                                |
| skip_package_ipa                                                  | false                                                                                                                                |
| skip_package_pkg                                                  | false                                                                                                                                |
| include_bitcode                                                   | false                                                                                                                                |
| build_path                                                        | /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-14                                                                            |
| result_bundle                                                     | false                                                                                                                                |
| buildlog_path                                                     | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                                                                                                   |
| destination                                                       | generic/platform=iOS                                                                                                                 |
| xcodebuild_formatter                                              | xcpretty                                                                                                                             |
| xcodebuild_command                                                | xcodebuild                                                                                                                           |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution                              | false                                                                                                                                |
| disable_package_automatic_updates                                 | false                                                                                                                                |
| use_system_scm                                                    | false                                                                                                                                |
| xcode_path                                                        | /Applications/Xcode_14.0.app                                                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|                                                                   Generated Build Command                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Option                                                                                                                               | Value                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| set -o pipefail &&                                                                                                                   |                      |
| xcodebuild                                                                                                                           |                      |
| -workspace ./iOS-App.xcworkspace                                                                                            |                      |
| -scheme XXXXXXXX                                                                                                                     |                      |
| -configuration Release                                                                                                               |                      |
| -destination                                                                                                                         | generic/platform=iOS |
| -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-14/XXXXXXXX-iOS-Nightly\ 2023-02-14\ 18.27.48.xcarchive          |                      |
| build_type='DEBUG' branch_key='key_test_bfXuy2uobV1CiIwXKPjvJkboDCji7F9C' application_environment='DEV' -skipPackagePluginValidation |                      |
| clean                                                                                                                                |                      |
| archive                                                                                                                              |                      |
| | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/XXXXXXXX-iOS-App-XXXXXXXX.log                                                                   |                      |
| | xcpretty                                                                                                                           |                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+

INFO [2023-02-14 18:27:48.71]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./iOS-App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-14/iOS-Nightly\ 2023-02-14\ 18.27.48.xcarchive build_type='DEBUG' branch_key='key_test_bfXuy2uobXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF9C' application_environment='DEV' -skipPackagePluginValidation clean archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/iOS-App.log | xcpretty

INFO [2023-02-14 18:44:01.07]: $ /usr/bin/xcrun /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.211.0/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/gym_config20230214-3171-ldx1w.plist' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-14/iOS-Nightly\ 2023-02-14\ 18.27.48.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/gym_output20230214-3171-tqoii3' build_type='DEBUG' branch_key='key_test_bfXuy2uobV1CiIwXKPjvJkboDCji7F9C' application_environment='DEV' -skipPackagePluginValidation 

INFO [2023-02-14 18:44:01.66]: ▸ + xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/gym_config20230214-3171-ldx1w.plist -archivePath '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-14/iOS-Nightly 2023-02-14 18.27.48.xcarchive' -exportPath /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/gym_output20230214-3171-tqoii3 build_type=DEBUG branch_key=key_test_bfXuy2uobV1CiIwXKPjvJkboDCji7F9C application_environment=DEV -skipPackagePluginValidation
```

Comment: @BillMote We have also found that the app is crashing if we are generating the build from CI job. If we are manually creating the build and uploading on Testflight, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to verify that a relatively new Xcode setting (manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber) will alter our SDK’s ability to verify the versions of its components. The issue only surfaces when the application is published to the App Store or Testflight, and is not detectable during the build. The team felt that they needed to rollback the version and fix the issue in the next release.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan. Please let us know when this fix is released.

Comment: Please update to the latest release (MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.12 & SFMCSDK 1.0.8)